# ListView performance issues within Grid row

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I've started my first project on Nativescript-vue and there's a simple issue I don't understand.

I have a ListView that is a part of grid layout with dynamically generated height (*)
If I set the height to static value, ListView works fine, however, I want my ListView to take up all remaining height, but in this case it's very laggy on both ios and android devices.

I have prepared the playground to demonstrate my issue here: 
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=sIEdwg

```
<template>
<Page>
    <GridLayout rows="auto,auto,*,auto" columns="auto">
        <GridLayout row="0" ref="navStatusBar" class="navStatusBar"
            verticalAlignment="top" height="40" width="100%" rows="auto"
            columns="auto,*,auto,auto,auto">
            <!-- some header static blocks -->
            <Label text="sample header" />
        </GridLayout>
        <GridLayout row="1" ref="navTab" class="navTab"
            verticalAlignment="top" height="50" width="100%" rows="auto"
            columns="auto,auto,auto">
            <!-- additional header blocks -->
            <Label text="additional header placeholder" />
        </GridLayout>
        <ListView for="item in jobList" class="list-group sent" row="2">
            <v-template if="item.item_type == 'job'">
                <Job :item="item"></Job>
            </v-template>
            <v-template if="item.item_type == 'date'">
                <Label class="date-block" :text="item.date"
                    textWrap="true">
                </Label>
            </v-template>
        </ListView>
        <StackLayout row="3">
            <!-- some footer here -->
            <Label text="footer placeholder" />
        </StackLayout>
    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

Is there a way to make ListView behave as it does when row height is set statically (eg.: ...`<GridLayout rows="auto,auto,450,auto" columns="auto">`...) but make it to take all remaining height?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think so, it won't know what's the height of the list item and without knowing that it can not calculate the remaining height from required height. You might simply use a StackLayout instead of GridLayout and set fixed height to first child.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, StackLayout helped me.